# Fingerprint enroll using WinBio, sample number

Tags: c++, windows, fingerprint

I am trying to enroll a fingerprint using Windows Biometric Framework. The procedure is quite straightforward, but I would like to ask you if there is a defined number of samples (times the users swipes his finger) required to do an enrollment?

If this is hardware based, then it should change regarding the fingerprint reader you use, but i am wondering if this is an implementation specific.

I am copying the example from MSDN

> ```
> // Capture enrollment information by swiping the sensor with
> // the finger identified by the subFactor argument in the 
> // WinBioEnrollBegin function.
> ```

```
for (int swipeCount = 1;; ++swipeCount)
{
    wprintf_s(L"\n Swipe the sensor to capture %s sample.",
             (swipeCount == 1)?L"the first":L"another");

    hr = WinBioEnrollCapture(
            sessionHandle,  // Handle to open biometric session
            &rejectDetail   // [out] Failure information
            );

    wprintf_s(L"\n Sample %d captured from unit number %d.", 
              swipeCount, 
              unitId);

    if (hr == WINBIO_I_MORE_DATA)
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n    More data required.\n");
        continue;
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (hr == WINBIO_E_BAD_CAPTURE)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n  Error: Bad capture; reason: %d", 
                      rejectDetail);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioEnrollCapture failed. hr = 0x%x", hr);
            goto e_Exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n    Template completed.\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Can we know how many more data is required each time?

Comment: No, it depends on the sensor, the fingerprint clearance etc. Why not let Windows decide when the data is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to identify how many samples are required until the end of the fingerprint enrolment .
(The only reason I was looking for this number was in order to inform the user how many tries are required - bad thought...)